# Search hex dump in IDA pro remote debugger

Tags: ida, debugging

I am using IDA Pro to debug an ELF binary remotely.

While debugging, I want to search for a specific address in the hex dump. In Olly debugger, we have the option to follow any address or register in the hex dump. Is there a similar option in IDA Pro?

I noticed that IDA Pro has an option to synchronize the hex dump with a specific register. However, I need to search for a specific address, how do I do that?

I checked the Jump menu in IDA Pro and there was no option. The "Jump to address" or G option is to search in the code section. Is there a similar option for searching in hex dump as well?

Thanks.

Comment: If you click into the hex dump window first, then type G and enter an address, the hex dump will switch to that address, not the code window. Make sure to unset any "synchronize to code window" options first.